# How to get dropdown options without clicking each element (Selenium & Python)

Tags: python, selenium

I have the following segment of HTML code that I am trying to get the dropdown options from. I want to get the text ( , 90, 110, 145, 200) not the data-value.

```
<div class="select-box blue">
 <div class="select">
  <span>Select size</span>
  <i class="hy-angle-bottom"></i>
 </div>
 <input onchange="BrowsePCats.onNonKmatCategoryFiltSelectChange(this)" type="hidden" value=""/>
 <ul class="select-box-menu">
  <li data-value="">
   Select size</li>
  <li data-value="83265">90</li>
  <li data-value="83241">110</li>
  <li data-value="83249">145</li>
  <li data-value="83257">200</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

I have a similarly formatted dropdown on a separate page that I have been able to extract the information from (code below), but that involves clicking each item on the list. I won't be able to click in the html code above because clicking a dropdown options links to another page. In the code below I tried iterating through the each `<li>` tag and just printing the element text, but it always returned the first element (blank). What are my options for extracting dropdown options when they are in `<ul>` and `<li>` tags instead of the typical `<select>` and `<option>` tags?

```
for each in list(range(len(dropDowns))): #dropDowns is a list of elements that I found, and I am trying to get each dropdowns options
    try:
        options = [x for x in dropDowns[each].find_elements_by_tag_name("li")]
        for e in options:
            dropDowns[each].find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'select').click() #click to open dropdown
            time.sleep(1) #wait for dropdown to open
            e.click() #click the option that is desired
            print("element text: ", e.text)            
    except NoSuchElementException:
            print("There is no element with class name select")
    except ElementNotInteractableException:
            print("Element not interactable")
    finally:
        print("\n")
        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all li text values do the following. Grab all li tags inside the ul loop and skip the first li.

```
li_tags = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[@class='select-box-menu']//li")

 values=[li.text for li in li_tags[1:]]
```

Or use li.get_attribute('textContent')

Comment: Hello, when I use the code you suggested, the values are all blank.
`li_tags = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[@class='select-box-menu']//li")`
`li_values=[li.text for li in li_tags[1:]]`
`print(li_values) # returns ['', '', '', '']`

Comment: Try using li.get_attribute('textContent') instead of li.text.

Comment: If it's still empty than you have to call the method.

Comment: Using `li.get_attribute('textContent')` in place of `li.text` worked! Thank you for your help.